# In Symfony2, how to cascade ACL on associated entities when persisting the "master" entity?

Tags: symfony, acl, persist

I searched a lot but can't find anything related to that question. 
When persisting an entity and creating the related ACL, Symfony doesn't create any ACL for the foreign key entities of that entity (a OneToOne relationship for example).

Is it normal behavior ? 
If it is, how can I create all the acl (for the main entity and its associated entities) in one action (after persisting the main entity) ?

**Update:**

In the meantime I did it like this (only one foreign key, "relation",  in my example), but that's not really the answer to my question...

```
$manager->createACL($product);
$manager->createACL($product->getRelation());
```